# Wordpress - setting a custom post per category

Tags: wordpress

I have added the below code to the functions.php file to load different post templates per category. The code is doing what it is supposed to do. The issue I am facing is that when I open posts these load correctly but whilst loading an error is displayed for a instant saying "trying to get property of non-object in .......functions.php" How may I get rid of that error? Appreciate your help.

```
 /*  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    custom single posts per category
 */

add_filter('single_template', 'check_for_category_single_template');
function check_for_category_single_template( $t )
{
  foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) 
  { 
    if ( file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php"; 
    if($cat->parent)
    {
      $cat = get_the_category_by_ID( $cat->parent );
      if ( file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php";
    }
  } 
  return $t;
```

}

Comment: That error message will also include the line number that is causing the error. Without that, we cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It is referring line 28 which is:
if ( file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php") ) return get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-{$cat->slug}.php";

Comment: Also important to note that the error appears only (for an instant whilst loading) when I open pages in subcategories. Pages in categories don't trigger the error....

Comment: any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `trying to get property of non-object` means, you try to get a property of something that is not an object. So looking at your code you are getting two properties with `->`:  "slug" and "parent".

This gives us the hint, that the value saved in the `$cat` variable might not be an object.

You are using `get_the_category_by_ID` which gives you a name, not a category object. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_by_id/ So you cannot access any property. The problem is this: `get_the_category_by_ID( $cat->parent );` There is no parent property in $cat, because it only contains the name. You need to get the object to make use of the parent property. Moreover the property is called `category_parent`, and not `parent`.

```
$parent_id = $cat->category_parent;
$cat = get_category($parent_id);
```

This should solve your problem.

---

If it does not solve your problem, I wrote the code in another way. It shows single steps and maybe it is useful for you or some other users.

The function to get all your category objects is: `get_categories()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

You can save all the IDs of the categoires into a array. After that, you loop through each position of the array and check if the single post you are viewing has the same category ID. We can check if the post is in given categories using `in_category()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/

I did no testing, but the code can look something like:

```
add_filter('single_template', 'check_for_category_single_template');
function check_for_category_single_template() {
   
   // Get all category objects
   $categories = get_categories();
   // Array for IDs
   $categories_ids = [];
   
   foreach($categories as $category) {
      // add id to array
      array_push($categories_ids, $category->cat_ID);
   }
   
   // Loop through array of IDs
   foreach($categories_ids as $category_id) {
     
      // Check if ID equals current post category ID
      if ( in_category($category_id) ) {

         // get current category object
         $cat = get_category($category_id);

         // check if category has parent
         if( $cat->category_parent > 0 ) {
            $parent_id = $cat->category_parent;
            // get parent object
            $cat = get_category( $parent_id );
         }

         // get slug of category
         $cat_slug = $cat->slug;
         
         if ( file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-" .$cat_slug. ".php") ) {
            return get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-category-" .$cat_slug. ".php";
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the recommended change is still triggering the error. I also tested the code you provided, It's working fine with the exception of when I open posts from subcategories. The following errors appear:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home4/...../functions.php on line 51

Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$slug in /home4/...../functions.php on line 55

Line 51 is:
$cat = get_category( $parent_id->category_parent );

Line 55 is:
$cat_slug = $cat->slug;

How may I fix it please?

Comment: Oh I had typo `$cat = get_category( $parent_id->category_parent );` was wrong. Get_category just needs the ID. So I corrected the line to `get_category($parent_id)` So maybe give it another try